# Probability/Set theory problem

Tags: probability, statistics, elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

The problem is:

> In some country, there are 3 newspapers. 20% of the population read
>   newspaper A, 16% read B, and 14% read C. 8% of the population read
>   both A and B, 5% read A and C, and 4% read B and C. 4% read A, B
>   and C.

How to find the probability that someone read exactly 1 newspaper?

Currently i have:

$P((A\setminus (B\cup C))\cup(B\setminus (A\cup C))\cup(C\setminus (A\cup B))
=
P(A\setminus (B\cup C))+P(B\setminus (A\cup C))+P(C\setminus (A\cup B))
=P(A)-P(B\cup C)+P(B)-P(A\cup C)+P(C)-P(A\cup B)$

Where $P(B\cup C)=P(B)+P(C)-P(B\cap C)$ and similar for the others.

However this approach is leading me to a negative value.

What's the problem here?

Comment: Are you familiar with the inclusion-exclusion principle?

Comment: @KlausDraeger Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n_A$ be the proportion of people reading *only* A, $n_{A B}$ be the proportion reading *only* A and B, not C, $n_{A B C}$ be the proportion of people reading all three, etc. Then,

$$
\begin{align}
n_A + n_{A B} + n_{A C} + n_{A B C} &= 0.2 \\
n_B + n_{A B} + n_{B C} + n_{A B C} &= 0.16 \\
n_C + n_{A C} + n_{B C} + n_{A B C} &= 0.14 \\
n_{A B} + n_{A B C} &= 0.08 \\
n_{A C} + n_{A B C} &= 0.05 \\
n_{B C} + n_{A B C} &= 0.04 \\
n_{A B C} &= 0.04.
\end{align}
$$

7 equations, 7 unknowns. Now solve.

BTW your assumption $P(A \setminus (B\cup C)) = P(A) - P(B\cup C)$ is wrong. Part of the latter term encompasses those who don't read paper A, and you're subtracting that part from the total number of people who read A for no reason.

EDIT: of course, there's
$$
n_A + n_B + n_C + n_{A B} + n_{A C} + n_{B C} + n_{A B C} + n_0 = 1
$$
where $n_0$ is the proportion of people who don't read the papers. But you don't need that last bit to answer your question, only to solve for $n_A + n_B + n_C$.

Comment: What would be equivalent to $P(A \setminus (B\cup C))$?

Comment: In my language, it would just be $n_A$. In yours it would be
$P(A) - P(B \cup C) + P((B \cup C) \setminus A)$

Comment: I tought that $n_A=P(A)$ ... the probability that A happens.

Comment: No, $P(A)$ includes _all_ the people who read paper A. If you read my post, you see $n_A$ is the proportion of people who read _only_ paper A. $P(A) = n_A + n_{A B} + n_{A C} + n_{A B C}$.

Answer (score 1):

The number of people who read exactly one newspaper $  =$
$n(A)+n(B)+n(C) +3n(A\cap B\cap C)-2n(A\cap B)-2n(B\cap C)-2n(C\cap A)$
$= 20\%+16\% +14\%+3\cdot4\%-2\cdot(8\%+5\%+4\%) = 28\%$

---

Explanation for the formula:
[image]

We want to calculate $1+3+7$.
$1+3+7 = (1+2+4+5)+(3+2+5+6)+(7+6+4+5)-(3(5)+2(2)+2(4)+2(6))$

$3(5)+2(2)+2(4)+2(6) = 2(2+5)+2(6+5)+2(4+5)-3(5)$

These two equations give us:
$1+3+7 = (1+2+4+5)+(3+2+5+6)+(7+6+4+5)-(2(2+5)+2(6+5)+2(4+5)-3(5))$

$\implies n(\text{in only one set}) = n(A)+n(B)+n(C) +3n(A\cap B\cap C)-2n(A\cap B)-2n(B\cap C)-2n(C\cap A)$

Comment: Can you explain this a little better?

Comment: @Wyvern666 Sure.

Comment: What is the second ecuation: $3(5)+2(2)+2(4)+2(6)$?

Comment: @Wyvern666 we wish to simply the negative terms in equation 1. So we consider them separately in such a way that we can form those sets, the cardinal number of which we know.

Comment: Yes, but for example when you say $3(5)$ what exactly are you counting?

Comment: 3 times the number of elements in $5$.

Comment: Ok, so you are using inclusion/exclusion here?

Comment: Yes, although the principle is so logical that I don't think of it while doing set operations.

Comment: Ok, i see. Thanks for your answer!!